# VBA : use of With with a space

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to clean my code that create a Dynamic Cross Table

I have a lot of fields to add, and I was thinking about using With :

```
 Ws.PivotTables(DCT_Name).AddDataField Ws.PivotTables(DCT_Name).PivotFields("Quantity"), "Total Qty", xlSum
```

to change to this :

```
With Ws.PivotTables(DCT_Name).AddDataField Ws.PivotTables(DCT_Name)
    .PivotFields ("Quantity"), "Total Qty", xlSum
```

But that doesn't work...

Am I forced to do :

```
With Ws.PivotTables(DCT_Name)
    .AddDataField Ws.PivotTables(DCT_Name).PivotFields ("Quantity"), "Total Qty", xlSum
```

Thanks for you answers!

Answer (score 2):

No, it should read

```
With Ws.PivotTables(DCT_Name)
    .AddDataField .PivotFields ("Quantity"), "Total Qty", xlSum
```

In general the common prefix (the object) is put into the With statement.

Comment: I tought it was gonna work but it gave me an error... "Error 1004 : Error defined by application or object"